# How to Make Wordpress Default gallery responsive on mobile?

Tags: images, css, gallery, responsive

I have read about the subject in many blogs and forums but I have not achieved anything.

What I would like to do on my page is the following:

[decalaveras.com](http://decalaveras.com)

On this page, when accessed from mobile, it automatically goes from 3 columns to 1 column in the image gallery.

Does anyone help me get this?

I use the same theme, twenty sixteen.

Comment: I visited your site, but it already performs the responsive behavior you describe. Could you clarify your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They achieve this by using [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) .

Here are the specific ones controlling the gallery width.

```
@media(max-width: 720px){
    .gallery-item{
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 480px){
    .gallery-item{
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Add those into your style.css and see if they work.

Comment: I've added it to the end of the style.css file and it keeps showing 3 columns on mobile device

Comment: you will need to use the browser inspector to try to figure it out.  maybe container divs have a different class or they are being overwrote by something else

Comment: you can check my page here: desupervivencia.top

Comment: I edited the styles to use max-width.  Copy the above and paste them at the end of your style.css file.  I tested this on your site and it should work

Comment: Now it works for me. I do not know why it works only in an incognito window
Thank you very much very kind. And forgive my fatal English