# making wordpress gallery responsive

Tags: gallery, responsive

I'm using a 4 column native wordpress gallery on my homepage: https://www.peace-ed-campaign.org/ (see just below the slider).

When viewed on mobile, the 4 columns/images remain side-by-side and shrink to the point of being useless.  I'd like the mobile responsive to adjust to either 2 or 1 image...

I've seen several threads here on this... but all answers date back to 2018.  None seem to work anymore.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Other threads I've tried:

[How to Make Wordpress Default gallery responsive on mobile?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/314538/how-to-make-wordpress-default-gallery-responsive-on-mobile/314542?newreg=cf62ea34e6a748d0a1373aae3bebdad6)

[Making WordPress Gallery (.gallery-item) Responsive?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185961/making-wordpress-gallery-gallery-item-responsive)

Currently trying this with no luck:

```
/* For displaying single column on mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item {
     width: 100%;
 }
}

.gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item:nth-child(4n+1) {
     clear: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set `max-width` Just add `max-width:100%` below your code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
 .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item { 
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
 } 
}
```

Comment: Yes!! Success!! Thank you.